# Bar chart using Chart.js

Tags: chart.js

I am trying to implement a bar chart using chart.js(http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#bar-chart). I was able to create the chart, but I require to have a scrollable horizontal axis. I haven't been able to find any pointers to the same. Can anyone please assist me in this?

Comment: Try scaleShowHorizontalLines: true for horizontal lines

Comment: Thanks, overriding the size of the canvas size set by the plugin helped. I have another question though. Is it possible to provide different font colors to x-axis labels and y-axis labels?

Comment: The documentation on Chart.js can probably be of more assistance. It's pretty extensive.

Comment: simple example step-by-step guide http://codepedia.info/2015/04/chart-js-simple-bar-chart-example-using-html5-canvas-jquery/